# Setting a Bundle as user data in account manager

Tags: android, accountmanager, android-authenticator

I'm developing at an own authenticator in the android account manager. And when the user logs in, i want to save some user specific data when i add the account in the account mananager.

I'm using the method from the AccountManager:

```
public boolean addAccountExplicitly (Account account, String password, Bundle userdata)
```

The third parameter is a bundle, that could only contain String key-value pairs, i think... But in my case i want to put a bundle in a bundle..
It looks like this:

```
userData _"Parameter1":"bundleOfParameter1"
        |_"Paramter2": "bundleOfParamter2" 
        |_....
```

After the account was added in the account manager, i try to get the userdata with:

```
public String getUserData (Account account, String key)
```

and it returns null, i think because they don't set the userdata during adding in the accountmanager because it is a bundle and not a String...

Have someone an idea how to pass the problem? Or had someone the same problem and can help?
My idea is to save the userdata bundles as Strings with Bundle.toString(), and later on to transform the string to a bundle?

(Execuse me for my !perfect english...)

Comment: Had the exact same issue. Solved the issue by setting userdata after the call to addAccountExplicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your data in a custom class that implements Parcelable instead of a bundle inside a bundle

Comment: Can you give more details about how to  do that?

Comment: say you want to pass about a persons name and age. create a class Person.    `Person { String name; int age; }`.     pass your class through this[link]http://www.parcelabler.com/ site to make it parcelable . then in your bundle add the class instance by calling `bundle.putParcelable(**)`

Comment: Thank you for spending time to answer, i solved the problem otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the user-data with `addAccountExplicitly(Account, String, Bundle)`. Instead, just pass **null** for bundle when calling `addAccountExplicitly(Account, String, Bundle)`. After that, call `setUserData(Account, String, String)` to add the user-data. Remember to call `setUserData(Account, String, String)` right **after** calling `addAccountExplicitly(Account, String, Bundle)`